# Is it possible to run again docker containers on windows 10 machine after restart of docker toolbox?

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10, docker-toolbox

I have to restart my windows 10 machine from time to time and it is annoying to reinstall my containers again. Is there away to restart all previous containers after the restart of windows 10 and docker toolbox and not to reinstall containers?

Comment: Yes. `docker run`.

Comment: Re**install** or re**start**?  Are you containers marked to be deleted after being stopped?

Comment: After the restart of my machine, I run the tool box and when I exec docker run --name to run my container I get the error that is  is already in use by container and I have to remove the container and run it again. I want to find a way to resurrect containers after the restart of the toolbox and not to remove containers and run them again. Is there a way to do this ? Thanks